# KDE Plasma screen going dark even though screen dimming is disabled

Tags: kde, power-management, screensaver, plasma-5

My screen keeps dimming (or going blank) after several minutes of inactivity. Normally I don't mind, but the other night, I was giving a presentation and connected to a projector. If, for example, I took a question and was talking for a few minutes without minding the computer, *both* the laptop screen and the projector would go dark.

Energy saving settings:

- On AC Power

  - Dim screen **disabled**
  - Screen energy-saving **disabled**
  - Suspend session **disabled**
- On Battery

  - Same

The KDE app menu, when I search for "screen saver," says 1/ Get screensaver and 2/ Get caffeine -- I take this to mean that I don't have a screensaver installed that would be overriding the power settings. (Also the System Settings panel doesn't have anything for a screensaver.)

Why is it doing this?

If the solution is to install and use Caffeine when I need the screen not to shut off, OK, but there are entries in the system settings panel about this, and they are not being respected. Users might reasonably expect that unchecking "dim screen" would stop the screen from dimming, but that hasn't been my experience. If this is happening because of a screensaver, then... why would that be the case if the screensaver is not installed?

```
Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-68-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-12500H
Memory: 15.4 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Graphics
```